# Resharper moving top brace next to if statement. How to have on new line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, editor, resharper, resharper-8.0

My Resharper 8 is auto formatting on the end brace. The top brace moves to the end of the IF statement line. How can I have it format to the next line.

Starting statement

```
if (condition)
{
    var x = new foo();
}
```

When the bottom brace is removed and retyped this is the result. The top brace moves to the end of the line above.

```
if (condition) {
    var x = new foo();
}
```

**The desired result is the initial starting statement.**

How can I change the options in R#8 to fix this? I have tried changing options in the `C# / Formatting / Braces layout` options.
[image]

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this question.  It also does it with for loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.  Under Formatting Style --> Line Breaks and Wrapping --> Preserve Existing Formatting, change "Break line in a block with a single statement" to "break line".[image: this is where in resharper you change it]